# Does Apache Spark SQL support MERGE clause?

Tags: sql, hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

Does Apache Spark SQL support MERGE clause that's similar to Oracle's MERGE SQL clause?

```
MERGE into <table> using (
  select * from <table1>
    when matched then update...
       DELETE WHERE...
    when not matched then insert...
)
```

Comment: Adding a comment for visibility of @amardeep-kohli's answer. This is now possible with the `delta` format (by databricks, but many features are now also open source). https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-update.html#upsert-into-a-table-using-merge

Answer (score 18):

Spark does support MERGE operation using Delta Lake as storage format. The first thing to do is to save the table using the `delta` format to provide support for transactional capabilities and support for DELETE/UPDATE/MERGE operations with spark

Python/scala:
`df.write.format("delta").save("/data/events")`

SQL: `CREATE TABLE events (eventId long, ...) USING delta`

Once the table exists, you can run your usual SQL Merge command:

```
MERGE INTO events
USING updates
ON events.eventId = updates.eventId
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET events.data = updates.data
WHEN NOT MATCHED
  THEN INSERT (date, eventId, data) VALUES (date, eventId, data)
```

The command is also available in Python/Scala:

```
DeltaTable.forPath(spark, "/data/events/")
  .as("events")
  .merge(
    updatesDF.as("updates"),
    "events.eventId = updates.eventId")
  .whenMatched
  .updateExpr(
    Map("data" -> "updates.data"))
  .whenNotMatched
  .insertExpr(
    Map(
      "date" -> "updates.date",
      "eventId" -> "updates.eventId",
      "data" -> "updates.data"))
  .execute()
```

To support Delta Lake format, you also need the delta package as dependency in your spark job:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.delta</groupId>
  <artifactId>delta-core_x.xx</artifactId>
  <version>xxxx</version>
</dependency>
```

See https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-update.html#upsert-into-a-table-using-merge for more details

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 2):

As of Spark 3.0, Spark offers a very clean way of doing the merge operation using the spark delta table.
https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-update.html#upsert-into-a-table-using-merge

Answer (score 1):

It does not. As of now (it might change in the future) Spark doesn't support `UPDATES`, `DELETES` or any other variant of record modification.

It can only overwrite existing storage (with different implementation depending on the source) or append with plain `INSERT`.

Answer (score 1):

you can write your custom code: Below code you can edit to go with merge instead of Insert. Make sure this is computation heavy operations. but get y

```
  df.rdd.coalesce(2).foreachPartition(partition => {
  val connectionProperties = brConnect.value
  val jdbcUrl = connectionProperties.getProperty("jdbcurl")
  val user = connectionProperties.getProperty("user")
  val password = connectionProperties.getProperty("password")
  val driver = connectionProperties.getProperty("Driver")
  Class.forName(driver)

  val dbc: Connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, user, password)
  val db_batchsize = 1000
  var pstmt: PreparedStatement = null

  partition.grouped(db_batchsize).foreach(batch => {
    batch.foreach{ row =>
      {
        val id = row.id
        val fname = row.fname
        val lname = row.lname
        val userid = row.userid
        println(id, fname)
        val sqlString = "INSERT employee USING   " +
        " values (?, ?, ?, ?) "

        var pstmt: PreparedStatement = dbc.prepareStatement(sqlString)
        pstmt.setLong(1, row.id)
        pstmt.setString(2, row.fname)
        pstmt.setString(3, row.lname)
        pstmt.setString(4, row.userid)
        pstmt.addBatch()
        pstmt.executeBatch()
      }

    }
    //pstmt.executeBatch()
    dbc.commit()
    pstmt.close()
  })
  dbc.close()
} )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working over Spark, maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46474476/spark-scala-save-dataframe-to-a-table-with-overwrite-mode/46475249#46475249) answers could help you to lead with the merge issue using DataFrames.

Anyway, reading [some](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.2/bk_data-access/content/new-feature-insert-values-update-delete.html) documentation of Hortonworks, it says that Merge sentence is supported in Apache Hive 0.14 and later.

Answer (score 0):

There is an Apache project - Apache Iceberg - which creates a table format type with editing capabilities, including MERGE:

https://iceberg.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-writes/