# How to delete rows in database with Spark?

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark, pyspark

I know how to insert rows

```
    df.write \
        .format('jdbc') \
        .option("url", url) \
        .option("dbtable", table) \
        .option("user", user) \
        .option("password", password) \
        .option("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver") \
        .mode('append') \
        .save()
```

But how to delete rows?
like.

```
df = [Row(id=1), Row(id=2), ... ]

=> DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE id in df ...
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Use a native JDBC connection for deletes using `PreparedStatement` ad `executeUpdate()`

Comment: You can't. You will need to go back to the old JDBC way to do this. You'll have to iterate over the rows you want to delete, and delete it batch-wise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spark doesn't support it.
But I've done it with foreachPartition (Just use dataframe data..)

Like this [Does Apache Spark SQL support MERGE clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46613907/does-apache-spark-sql-support-merge-clause)

```
df.rdd.coalesce(2).foreachPartition(partition => {
  val connectionProperties = brConnect.value
  val jdbcUrl = connectionProperties.getProperty("jdbcurl")
  val user = connectionProperties.getProperty("user")
  val password = connectionProperties.getProperty("password")
  val driver = connectionProperties.getProperty("Driver")
  Class.forName(driver)
  val dbc: Connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, user, password)
  val db_batchsize = 1000
  val sqlString = "INSERT employee USING values (?, ?, ?, ?)"

  var pstmt: PreparedStatement = dbc.prepareStatement(sqlString)
  partition.grouped(db_batchsize).foreach(batch => {
    batch.foreach{ row =>
      {
        val id = row.id
        val fname = row.fname
        val lname = row.lname
        val userid = row.userid

        var pstmt: PreparedStatement = 
        pstmt.setLong(1, row.id)
        pstmt.setString(2, row.fname)
        pstmt.setString(3, row.lname)
        pstmt.setString(4, row.userid)
        pstmt.addBatch()
      }
    }
    pstmt.executeBatch()
    dbc.commit()
  })
  dbc.close()
})
```