# Implementing Merge using Dataframes (Scala/Spark)

Tags: apache-spark

I am Very new to spark scala programing. Gurus, Please point me in right direction or correct if I am going in wrong direction.

I am trying to implement merge in scala /spark which natively does not support  MERGE. My target database is HIVE.

Spark version : 2.x

if  anyone has implemented solution like this please share your thought process

Thanks in advance

Update : ***As asked by one of the member What do I mean by merge***

Table : emp (target)
emp_id(primary key)   emp_name   salary 
100                   Bob        1000   
 
200                   Kelley     2000   
300                   Ron        1200

Table : emp_ext (source table from where we load data) 
emp_id(primary key)   emp_name   salary 
100                   Bob        1100  (Row Changed) 
200                   Kelley     2000  (No  Change)  
300                   Ron        1200  (No  Change)

Final state of table emp 
======================== 
emp_id(primary key)   emp_name   salary  
100                   Bob        1100    
200                   Kelley     2000    
300                   Ron        1200

Comment: What do you mean by merge?

Comment: My guess is that you are looking for either `join` or `union`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to do something like
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46474476/spark-scala-save-dataframe-to-a-table-with-overwrite-mode/46475249#46475249)

Its about the merge of a DF with a Hive Table.